# Nilpotent short games of odd order

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Is there a short game $G \ne 0$ such that $G + G + G = 0$? It seems to me like such a game shouldn't exist, but I am unable to prove it. Can anyone give an example of such a game, or a proof that one doesn't exist?

Also, is there any short game $G$ such that an odd number of copies of $G$ summed together gives $0$? Note that if there is not, then any nilpotent game has order a power of 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there non-zero combinatorial games of odd order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730010/are-there-non-zero-combinatorial-games-of-odd-order)

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I was asking. Thank you for finding it.